# are there any equation which tell us the energies of for example a neutron emitted during photodisintegration from the energy of radiation subjected

Tags: particle-physics, large-hadron-collider

So my question is that if we have a pile of Be9 which can decay upon being subject to radiation with energies of 13 Mev. So that 13 Mev represents the binding energy of the Nucleas of Beryllium 9? and further is there any way we can determine the energy of the particles given off by this photo-disintegration of spallation of another element. Hope this makes sense cause im a little confused by this whole topic

Comment: Where do you get 13MeV from? The threshold for photodisintegration of ⁹Be is about 1.68 MeV.